# How can I unset all document properties except for one or two in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents about entities that have `status` property that could be `1` or `0`. Every document contains a lot of data and occupies space.
I want to get rid of most of the data on the documents with `status` equal `0`.

So, I want every document in the collection that looks like

```
{
   _id: 234,
   myCode: 101,
   name: "sfsdf",
   status: 0,    
   and: 23243423.1,
   a: "dsf",
   lot: 3234,
   more: "efsfs",
   properties: "sdfsd"
}
```

...to be a lot smaller

```
{
    _id: 234,
    mycode: 101,
    status: 0
}
```

So, basically I can do

```
db.getCollection('docs').update(
    {'statusCode': 0},
    { 
        $unset: { 
           and: "", 
           a: "", 
           lot: "", 
           more: "", 
           properties: "" 
       } 
    }, 
    {multi:true}
)
```

But there are about 40 properties which would be a huge list, and also I'm not sure that all the objects follow the same schema.

Is there a way to unset all except two properties?

Comment: You should just overwrite instead of unset. Something like `db.getCollection('docs').update(
    {'statusCode': 0},
   {
    _id: 234,
    mycode: 101,
    status: 0
}
)` and use bulk write.

Comment: I thought of that, but thare are two flaws: 1. overwriting doesn't work with `multi` parameter. 2. I need to keep the `mycode`s that could differ, and I don't know how to save them using this approach.

Comment: Sorry I was still updating my comment. Check again.

Comment: Yes, but how can I keep various `mycode`s untouched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do here is to actually throw all the possible properties to [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) and let it do it's job. You cannot "wildcard" such arguments so there really is not a better way without writing to another collection.

If you don't want to type them all out or even know all of them, then simply perform a process to "collect" all the other top level properties.

You can do this for example with `.mapReduce()`:

```
var fields = db.getCollection('docs').mapReduce(
  function() {
    Object.keys(this)
      .filter(k => k !== '_id' && k  !== 'myCode')
      .forEach( k => emit(k,1) )
  },
  function() {},
  {
    "out": { "inline": 1 }   
  }
).results.map( o => o._id )
 .reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{ [curr]: "" }),{})
```

Gives you an object with the full fields list to provide to [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) as:

```
{
    "a" : "",
    "and" : "",
    "lot" : "",
    "more" : "",
    "name" : "",
    "properties" : "",
    "status" : ""
}
```

And that is taken from all possible top level fields in the whole collection.

You can do the same thing with `.aggregate()` in MongoDB 3.4 using `$objectToArray`:

```
var fields = db.getCollection('docs').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "fields": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
        "as": "d",
        "cond": {
          "$and": [
            { "$ne": [ "$$d.k", "_id" ] },
            { "$ne": [ "$$d.k", "myCode" ] }          
          ]
        }
      }
    }  
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$fields" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$fields.k"  
  }}
]).map( o => o._id )
  .reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{ [curr]: "" }),{});
```

Whatever way you obtain the list of names, then simply send them to [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/):

```
db.getCollection('docs').update(
  { "statusCode": 0 },
  { "$unset": fields },
  { "multi": true }
)
```

Bottom like is that [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) does not care if the properties are present in the document or not, but will simply remove them where they exist.

---

The alternate case is to simply write everything out to a new collection if that also suits your needs. This is a simple use of [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) as an aggregation pipeline stage:

```
db.getCollection('docs').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "statusCode": 0 } },
  { "$project": { "myCode": 1  } },
  { "$out": "newdocs" }
])
```